# OpenVPN setup using only .openvpn and .key

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, open-source, windows-server-2012

I have a tunnel purchased from PRQ.se, previsouly I've been running it on Windows Server 2003 but I've moved on to Windows Server 2012 R2 this week. The OpenVPN program that PRQ recommends from http://openvpn.se/ was last updated in October 2006 and I feel like I should look for more updated software if at all possible.

*Now, it should be said that normally I would ask the company's support about this but they compleyely, utterly suck when it comes to support. PRQ aren't helpful and can take days or even weeks to respond (if at all). Not seldom they can get downright rude when you try to talk with them. However, the service is fairly reliable and they provide a static IP which I need. They also have a strict privacy policy for Anonymous guys like me (no questions answered to third parties to date, at least as far as the public knows).*

Anyway, they provide two files:

- prq.openvpn
- prq.key

The first has configuration stuff (what IP to connect to and a mention of the "prq.key" filename). The second contains the "2048 bit OpenVPN static key". Both of these files are placed in a folder named **config** in the OpenVPN installation directory.

The old 2006 program from openvpn.se was started this way:

```
openvpn-gui-1.0.3.exe --connect prq.openvpn
```

That did everything, the tunnel was up and running.

The reason I need help in this thread is because when I search the net for "openvpn" I get taken to http://openvpn.net/ - the official OpenVPN site I reckon. However when I get there it seems like a scam, or at least like a sponsored advertisment.

Links to "privatetunnel" are everywhere, even with the word *"referral"* plain in sight in the URLs. I downloaded the client in ignorance and was surprised to find something that looked incredibly sponsored. A uninstall followed shortly.

There seem to be a "community" section on openvpn.net that looks alright but after the fiasco with the first client download from there I'm not risking anything - I want help with this.

I'm reaching out to you guys, **what should I install to get things to work with what I got?** What is compadible with prq.openvpn and prq.key?

Also, some threads that I encountered during some searching on the net expressed issues with getting OpenVPN to work on Server 2012 - if anybody here has any experience with that and would like to give advice on the subject I would be much obliged.

Comment: The 2.3.2 release from http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html looks appropriate but if someone can confirm this I would be grateful. Don't want to mess up a stable new OS with fishy software.

Answer (score 0):

Went with the 2.3.2 community release from:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html

Worked just like the old one, no problems at all. Didn't have to do anything special either, just install and it was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The site to which you refer **http://openvpn.net/** is the official website for the Free Open Source Software Project **OpenVPN Community Edition**

Privatetunnel is an Online VPN Service Provider from the same Company that owns the OpenVPN Trademark.

They are fully legitimate and extremely widely used products.